# AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp Not Retrieving additional claims from UserInfoEndpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, microsoft-identity-platform

Here is a snippet of my startup so far:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownStreamApi(initialScopes)
.AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("GraphAPI"))
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

With that above config, I get the login screen as I should, I see that the back-channel http requests are hitting .well-known-config, getting the endpoints, posting the signin results to my redirectUrl.  I also see that the middleware is reaching out to the token endpoint and getting an access_token with the correct scopes (including User.ReadBasic.All), but it is NOT using that token to hit the userInfo endpoint and retrieve those claims associated with User.ReadBasic.All.

Am I configuring it wrong, or do I need to manually configure this somewhere?  Seems stupid if I have to manually config it, when the normal OpenIdConnect middleware has an option you set to true to have it automatically get these claims for you.

Edit:  I forgot to mention that if I use OpenIdConnect middleware instead, I can get all these claims no problem, so it's not an Azure config issue.

Please help.

Comment: `but it is NOT using that token to hit the userInfo endpoint and retrieve those claims associated with User.ReadBasic.All.` What does this mean?Does it give you any error message or status code?

Comment: No error, the middleware simply never makes an http request to the userinfo endpoint using the access_token it got from the token endpoint.  Even when I manually set "GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint" to true, that call isn't happening.  I spent the better part of yesterday using dotPeek to debug the middleware, but it's a giant pain.

Comment: The "code id_token" flow works as follows: The client requests signin and provides the required client credentials, if the user is correctly signed in, the IDP will return an authorization_code and an id_token.  The id_token will have some base level claims but not ALL to avoid ticket bloat.  IF the client needs more claims it will use the authorization_code against a token endpoint, then use the resulting access_token against the userinfo endpoint.  Middleware has an option GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint to enable/disable. Works in openConnectMIddleware not in MicrosoftIdentity middleware

Comment: So what is your UserInfo endpoints?Could you share more details and tell us which line does not work?

Comment: @Rena it's just the standard https://graph.microsoft.com/{tenantidhere}/oidc/userinfo.  It's defined in the discovery document that the middleware is using to hit the token endpoint and get the token it needs to hit the userinfo endpoint, but it's just not hitting.  My gut tells me that that option in the new IdentityPlatform middleware is not properly getting used...

Answer (score 1):

If you see the data/claims coming back from the UserInfo endpoint (if you look at the traffic in tools like Fiddler) but you don't see them in the ClaimsPrincipal user object?

If that is the case, then you need to do some claims transformation and explicitly map the missing claims. Because by default .NET will not include all the claims received into the user object.

If you were using AddOpenIdConnect directly, then you would write code like this to do the mapping:

```
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("sub", "sub");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("name", "name");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("given_name", "given_name");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("family_name", "family_name");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("profile", "profile");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("email", "email");
```

I am not sure how this is exactly done when you use AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp, but I would assume you will be able to find something like the above with the libraries that you use.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: I'm actually mapping all with options.ClaimActions.MapAll(). This isn't an issue with the claims being mapped after being recieved... The UserInfo endpoint isn't being hit at all.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding

`JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;`

to `Startup.cs`? This flag ensures that the `ClaimsIdentity` claims collection will be built from the claims in the token. This is required to be instantiated before the `OpenIdConnectOptions` starts getting configured.